# Problem installing Perl's Crypt::SSLeay on Solaris 10

Tags: perl, ssl, solaris

I'm trying to install the `Crypt::SSLeay` perl module and it keeps failing.

Perl is v5.8.8; Solaris is 5.10 and is on Intel hardware.

I'm using the CPAN module to attempt the install and the problems start when it gets to the 'make test' stage:

```
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/local/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00-basic......1/12
#   Failed test 'use Crypt::SSLeay;'
#   in t/00-basic.t at line 6.
#     Tried to use 'Crypt::SSLeay'.
#     Error:  Can't load '/.cpan/build/Crypt-SSLeay-0.58-tvJe1E/blib/arch/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so' for module Crypt::SSLeay: ld.so.1: perl: fatal: libssl.so.0.9.8: open failed: No such file or directory at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i86pc-solaris/DynaLoader.pm line 230.
#  at (eval 3) line 2
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 3) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/00-basic.t line 6.
```

I've verified that ld.so.1 and libssl.so.0.9.8 both exist and as far I can tell, OpenSSL is installed (pkginfo shows 'OpenSSL Libraries (Usr)').

Anyone have any thoughts on what the problem may be?

Dave

Comment: This looks familiar to a bug I filed against `0.58_01`. See https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=62683 It is on my TODO list, but I have not been able to get around to it. I cannot reproduce it and what might be causing the problem is not immediately apparent to me. This is compounded by the fact that I do not have access to a Solaris system and have very little experience with it. So, could you please add as much information as possible, including the full build log to the ticket above? Thank you.

Comment: Also, please try running `Makefile.PL` from the command line (using 0.58_01`) and provide the output.

Comment: @Sinan: I was hoping this would be something simple like maybe things weren't in the paths as expected, but I guess not.  :)  I've downloaded the 0.58_01 version and did a manual build.  I copied the results to a file and opened a new ticket (64014) at rt.cpan.org.  Let me know if you figure it out!  Until then, I guess I'll have to rewrite the script in some other language so I can use https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Elsewhere](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=64014) we figured out that the directory containing the SSL library files was not in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

The solution was:

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/ssl/lib
```

which is the library location reported by `Makefile.PL`.

I will add a note to the documentation and `Makefile.PL` output.

Thank you for your report and providing detailed information that enabled me to finally figure out what was going on with those test failures as well.

Now, I need to figure out how to ensure that the test scripts run with the correct `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: I should've known to check that; I've had to for other issues.  Thanks for your time!